# git lfs without local storage

Tags: git, git-lfs

I've migrated my repository to LFS and found that .git/lfs/objects is way too big.
Can I configure lfs not to store anything there and in case files are needed to download it straight to the repository folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this's not possible. Take a look at the git-lfs [official specification](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md):

```
...

The smudge filter runs as files are being checked out from the
Git repository to the working directory. Git sends the content
of the Git blob as STDIN, and expects the content to write to
the working directory as STDOUT.

- Read 100 bytes.
- If the content is ASCII and matches the pointer file format:
  . Look for the file in .git/lfs/objects/{OID-PATH}.
  . If it's not there, download it from the server.
  . Write its contents to STDOUT
- Otherwise, simply pass the STDIN out through STDOUT.

...
```

Comment: If we add "Delete file" right after "Write its contents to STDOUT" it will achieve the goal. Am I wrong?

Comment: How do you intend to do this? Actually, you could just delete the .git/lfs/objects regularly (cron).

Comment: It's up to git-lfs developers. They could add another flag and skip storing downloaded data. I think it is quite simple approach.
For the cron - it cannot be done on the "organisation" level.